# Is it possible to have an embedded external mongoose schema in another mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is it possible to make an array of external mongoose schemas?
When I run it like this, console says:

```
TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path `comments`, got value "undefined"
```

comment.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const commentScheme = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: String,
    author: {
        id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        username: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', commentScheme);
```

campground.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Comment = require('./comment');

const campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    desc: String,
    comments: [ Comment.commentSchema ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Campground', campgroundSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
you just need to replace

```
comments: [ Comment.commentSchema ]
```

with

```
comments: [ Comment.schema ]
```

good luck!